# bcdedit /enum firmware does not show grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu

I just installed `Lubuntu 18.04` on a laptop with `Windows 10` on another partition of its disk.
As a final step it installed `grub` as well.
But after booting it goes directly to `Windows 10` without giving me choice.

So I searched and found out that I can achieve it with `bcdedit.exe`.
When I run `bcdedit.exe /enum firmware` I can't see `grub` between the entries.

How can I fix it to be able to run the command
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` or similar. Or is there some other possibility to fix it?

Here is my BIOS settings. In the boot options there is only `Windows Boot Manager` and `Slimptype DVD`.
[image]

I was able to boot from DVD of `Lubuntu 17.04` because there was a possibility `Try Lubuntu without installing` and I'm posting
`fdisk -l` output
[image]

Comment: Have you disabled fast start up in windows?

Comment: Boot priority needs to be set in your BIOS settings so that GRUB/Ubuntu boots before Windows. You will need to consult your motherboard documentation.  Usually this involves holding down a key during boot to access your BIOS settings. It is a very bad idea to use Windows to fix any problems with Ubuntu or GRUB.

Comment: @Will I disabled fast start up in windows, but didn't help.

Comment: @Nmath I added a picture of my BIOS boot settings.

Comment: Do you see where it says "Boot Option Priorities" and for "Boot Option #1", you have Windows selected?  You need to change that to Ubuntu.

Comment: Release details (so we know the software stack you're taking about) may have been heplful

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Your using an EOL release may have complications; because of SHIM issues (*meaning systems may not boot*) [new 18.04 media was created](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) but it did not include *flavors* as they'd already reached EOL. This may **not** be your issue though

Comment: @guiverc Thank you, I will post `fdisk -l` output here in a while. I'd like to use `Lubuntu` because it's faster than Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. I installed `Ubuntu 18.04.6` and it solved my problem and it seems to be fast as well. I'm doing this for coworker laptop :-)

Comment: You can always switch the default GNOME desktop to others (inc. LXDE) as I've done it many times; alas not recently as 18.04 is no longer supported by the Lubuntu team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Your using an EOL release may have complications; because of SHIM issues (meaning systems may not boot) [new 18.04 media was created](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) but it did **not** include flavors as they'd already reached EOL.

> Unlike previous point releases, 18.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64 and
> arm64 installer media after the key revocation related to the BootHole
> vulnerability, re-enabling their usage on Secure Boot enabled systems.
> More detailed information can be found here:
>
> https://ubuntu.com/blog/grub2-secure-boot-bypass-2021

You can always switch the default GNOME desktop to others (inc. LXDE) as I've done it many times; alas not recently as 18.04 is no longer supported by the Lubuntu team.

Comment: It's likely your machine's SHIM database was updated through windows 10 updates given this worked, the new SHIM existing only on the 18.04.6 media (*which is the reason it was created!*)

Answer (score 1):

You must set Ubuntu first in BIOS settings for boot priority.

You currently have Windows selected, which means that Windows will boot before GRUB.

In order to get GRUB when you boot, you have to put Ubuntu before Windows in your boot priority.

Comment: This is what I naturally know. I did it so on another laptops, but this laptop has another BIOS. Do you see there Ubuntu in BIOS somewhere? I don't. I don't have experience with this BIOS. So, please post the steps I need to do, this is general advise that I already know.

Comment: All motherboards are different and unfortunately this is not something that is a part of any operating system. But you are on the screen with the option you need to change. It should be as easy as using the keyboard to navigate to that option and change it. However if you need more assistance at this point, you should consult the documentation for your motherboard. If that is not helpful enough, contact support for the manufacturer of your motherboard.  Hopefully though, it's something that you can figure out just using arrow keys on your keyboard.